# ¿Cuál es el concepto de inflate?

Tags: android

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu miMenu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mi_menu, miMenu);

    return true;
}
```

Dado este código, ¿qué significa realmente `inflate()`? Entiendo que el primer parámetro es tu menú creado pero ¿cómo se explica este método inflate con el segundo parámetro? ¿Qué se supone que hace este método con ese objeto Menú?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Inflar" un layout sería el proceso por el cual asocias a una vista, en este caso, el menú, su layout correspondiente, que tendrás guardado en un XML.

En este caso, en el primer parámetro le pasarías el layout `R.menu.mi_menu` dónde tendrías definidas las opciones que va a tener tu menú y, en el segundo parámetro, le pasarías tu menú para asociarle ese XML a la vista del menú.

Comment: Entiendo pero ese objeto Menu que recibe por parámetro el método ¿de donde viene?

Answer (score 0):

Ese objeto menu se puede crear porque fue importado de `import android.view.Menu`. Esto que comento es en kotlin, pero en esencia no debería de ser diferente en java.

Comment: Entonces, ¿a qué ser refiere _inflate_?

Comment: Cuando tú haces un inflate, asocias un archivo de kotlin/java a un archivo xml para poder construir el layout. Es decir, conectas el XML con el archivo correspondiente. El XML es usado para instanciar objetos view para que puedas crear objetos en kotlin. Hay más información en este link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477422/what-does-layoutinflater-in-android-do#3477483

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explícalo en la respuesta. La explicación no es para mí, sino para responder a la pregunta :) Lee [answer].